# Common code between two projects (repos?)

Tags: git

I know this has been asked in one way or another before, but I haven't found an answer which would answer my problem.

I have a two codebases A and B (aimed at different platforms) sharing most of their code. Let's call the shared code part C.

What I'd like to do is have a repo(s?) setup in a way that I can commit changes to part C from A, and then pulling B will get me the changes I made to C residing in A and the other way around.

For example, consider this dir structure:

```
A
|
|-- a.txt
|-- common.txt

B
|
|-- b.txt
|-- common.txt
```

If I make changes to `A/common.txt` and then pull `B` I want the changes I made to `A/common.txt` to be present in `B/common.txt`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

The only thing to mention, probably, is that you would be better off making changes in a completely different folder, then pushing the commits to the server and, finally, pulling from your code bases as submodules.

Comment: That's exactly the scenario I'm trying to avoid. The common code has no sense on it's own, it has to be wrapped by platform specific code to be ran, tested etc.

Comment: @MeLight I understand. On the other hand, it may be just a matter of a different point of view: the common code can (and should be) *unit*-tested on its own (you don't have to be able to run it separately), but the *integration* tests must be proper to every parent repository. It's like a standard library approach.

Answer (score 1):

"Submodules" in git were designed for this (among other things).  In your case, all of the "common" files would live in a subdirectory structure "inside" the "main" projects.  Then, that common directory structure would be a "submodule" that *both* "main" repos maintain references to.

See, for example, [this documentation on creating and using submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).